# Cordova Framework7 icon positioning

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

I have a Framework7 Cordova app and I'm trying to add a material design icon. Using this syntax is fine:

```
<i class="material-icons">search</i>
```

If I use this one the icon is not positioned correctly, it doesn't adapt to the `right` class specified on the parent div:

```
<i class="material-icons">&#xE8B6;</i>
```

Unfortunately I'm forced to use the latter syntax

Comment: What android version did you have when you test your app?

Comment: You should provide a fiddle for this problem so helping you would be much easier.

Comment: I found that if I use Android ver > 4.4.x it's perfectly fine. With Android ver < 4.4.x I get the issue. 4.4.x includes a major overhaul of the WebKit browser,  from a custom one to the Chromium engine